# HTC Chacha - random facebook notifications?! please help!

Tags: notifications, facebook, htc-chacha

My boyfriend bought me this phone about a week ago as an xmas present, and i've been very happy with it so far. Thing is, everytime I try to text somebody/look through my phone it constantly flashes 'to check-in places/to upload photos, please sign into facebook'. I don't have facebook & I just want to get rid of these random notifications that stop me enjoying my phone! Please help!

Comment: I don't know with which Android version that phone ships. If it's at least Android 4.x, you could go and "freeze" (disable) all those irrelevant bloatware apps like Facebook etc. Once disabled, they should bug you no longer. Also, for almost every app there's an alternative available -- so if nagging doesn't stop you could start replacing the SMS app, messenger, mail, photo... Plenty of choices available on the Google Playstore.

Comment: The HTC chacha is actually called "the Facebook phone" as its purpose is to make it easy to use with facebook. It even has a dedicated facebook button! Android 2.3. I would suggest changing ROM to cyanogenmod, a bit more complicated though. Android 4.0 with cyanogenmod 9 for example: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1665828